# DocuSign integration for Dynamics CRM 365 - Status update

Tags: dynamics-crm, docusignapi

We are using Dynamics CRM online and DocuSign integration.
Since the last update to version 6.6 we habe the issue that the status of the DocuSign transaction (Dynamics CRM record) doesn't get updated automatically.
In earlier versions like 6.5 of the DocuSign integration solution the status changed to completed some seconds later after signing the document. And also the signed document is not uploaded to Dynamics CRM or Sharepoint anymore.

We have customers which built workflows and business flows which rely on the status update.

To reproduce the issue open an account record in Dynamics CRM.
Click on the DocuSign button "Sign with DocuSign" and select a document.
You need to have at least one note with a document attached to your account record to use the "Sign with DocuSign" function.
Then sign the document with clicking on the link send to the email address.
Go back to your Dynamics CRM account record.
Click on Related -> DocuSign transactions.
You should see there your envelope which you have sent.
This record should have the envelope status completed as we have already signed the document.
But it has the status sent.

Additionally when you go to the timeline of the account record you would see the sign document.
Both stopped to work since the new version.

Can someone please help to solve the issue?

Wrote this question also to the [community](https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W00008Wk6Y6SAJ/dynamics-crm-integration-transactions-are-not-getting-updated).

**Update of 27.05.2020:** Issue solved by DocuSign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew, this issue is being investigated by DocuSign engineers and a fix should be ready within a week. You may need to update your version of DocuSign for Dynamics 365 when this issue is resolved. I'll clarify this when I know.